# Query CosmosDB nested structure JSON

Tags: json, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, qsqlquery, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using CosmosDB SQLAPI for one of our application. I query using Azure Storage Explore. JSON structure that I have finding it difficult to query.

```
{
    "countyid": 0,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "Elements": [
                    {
                        "ID": 11,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 16,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 3,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 5,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Elements": [
                    {
                        "ID": 486,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 492,
                        "V": false,
                        "R": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I need to get Elements[0] ID = 3,5,11,16 and Elements[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTFt.png) ID = 486,492

[CosmosDB Querying JSON edit window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTFt.png)

[Azure Storage Explorer window trying to query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zUWd.png)

[Query working without where condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEqed.png)

Comment: Don't know what your actual need. `I need to get Elements[0] ID = 3,5,11,16 and Elements[1] ID = 486,492`. You want filter data by this condition? What is the final structure of data?

Comment: I presume that you want query the first element array of data contains 3,5,11,16  ID meanwhile the second element array of data contains 486,492 ID. Am i right?

Comment: Something similar to SQL : SELECT c.data.Elements, c.data.Elements.Id FROM c
WHERE c.id in ('8a04fc64-904b-4530-98e8-914e951c0cbc')
ORDER BY c._ts DESC            . Final Result I am expecting is something like.Elements[0] 3
Elements[0] 5
Elements[0] 6
Elements[0] 11
Elements[1] 486
Elements[1] 492                                                                                                    Yes I want select array id's for each elements array.

Comment: Still confused...What's `Elements[0] 3 Elements[0] 5 Elements[0] 6 Elements[0] 11 Elements[1] 486 Elements[1] 492 `?  The result doesn't filter anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL

```SQL
select value array(select value z.ID from z in a.Elements)
from c
join b in c.data
join a in b
```

---

Result

```json
[
    [
        11,
        16,
        3,
        5
    ],
    [
        486,
        492
    ]
]
```

Comment: Awesome tiwahu, I am getting the ids as you stated with the query. But if I put a WHERE c.countyid = 0, it returns empty. Can you please help with that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join when you query nested array data, please try this sql:

```
SELECT distinct c.data  from c
join elem1 in c.data[0].Elements
join elem2 in c.data[1].Elements
where elem1.ID in(3,5,6,11) and elem2.ID in (486,492)
```

Comment: Jay, If you see this JSON   "data": [[{ "Elements" .....  Meaning after "data" field we have two square brackets then a curly braces and then "Elements" inside this structure. I was trying something like Select c.data...Elements event that is not supported in CosmosDB querying. First thing that is not even working for me is nested query to get the elements. Query provided is not returning.